# Append texts with onclick functions with different string parameters

Tags: javascript

I want to append some texts to my document, and clicking on these texts launches some functions with different string arguments.

I don't know why the following fonction does not make `onclick` work:

```
var strings = ["string1", "string2", "string3"];

function show (s) {
    alert(s);
}

for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    var elt = document.createElement('text');
    elt.innerHTML = strings[i];
    elt.onmouseover = "";
    elt.style = "cursor: pointer;";
    var s = "show(" + "'" + strings[i] + "'" + ")";
    elt.onclick = s;  
    document.body.appendChild(elt);
}
```

Here is the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/karilo/6/edit?html,js,output).

Additionally, I want to put `string1`, `string2` and `string3` line by line (ie, inserting `<br>` among them), and always inside the `<div class="padding">BEGIN ...</div>` (I don't think currently it is inside this `div`). Does anyone know how to realise this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Substitute `"span"` for `"text"` as parameter to `.createElement()`; add `"<br>"` after `strings[i]` when setting `.innerHTML` of `elt` element; set `onclick` with `Function.prototype.bind()` with `elt` as context, `strings[i]` as parameter to `show` function; create a variable referencing `.padding` element, to append created element to `.padding` element  call `.appendChild()` chained to `.padding` element instead of `document.body`

```js
var strings = ["string1", "string2", "string3"];

var padding = document.querySelector(".padding");

function show (s) {
    console.log(event.type);
    alert(s);
}

for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
    var elt = document.createElement("span");
    elt.innerHTML = strings[i] + "<br>";
    elt.style.cursor = "pointer";
    elt.onclick = show.bind(elt, strings[i]);  
    padding.appendChild(elt);
}
```

```html
  <div class="padding">
    BEGIN
    <br>
  </div>
```

Comment: So the default value of `onmouseover` is already empty, right?

Comment: @SoftTimur _"So the default value of onmouseover is already empty, right? "_ Yes, the element is dynamically created within `for` loop, `onmouseover` should be `null`. You can confirm this by including `console.log(this.onmouseover)` within `show` function

Comment: Regarding `div`, I think you create one `<div class="padding">` for each string. Actually, what I wanted is always appending these texts inside the same `div` of `BEGIN`, do you think if it is possible?

Comment: @guest271314, I wonder where does `event` come from in the for loop?

Comment: @yihangho `event` can be removed at both `for` loop and as parameter at `show`; you should still be able to access the `click` event` using `event` identifier within `show()` call. See updated post, http://jsbin.com/yogiriqaho/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 1):

```js
var strings = ["string1", "string2", "string3"];

function show(s) {
  alert(s);
}

for (var i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
  document.body.innerHTML += '<div class="padding" style="cursor: pointer" onclick="show(\'' + strings[i] + '\')">' + strings[i] + '</div>';
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/fabric/1.0/fabric.min.css">
</head>

<body class="ms-font-m">
  <div class="padding">
    BEGIN
    <br>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There are different ways to listen to events:

- Using event handler content attributes

  Their value is a string, stored in a HTML content attribute. You can set them in the HTML source, or via JavaScript through `setAttribute`:

  ```
  element.setAttribute('onclick', "show('" + strings[i] + "')");
  ```

  I strongly discourage using them. They are as evil as `eval`, are vulnerable to JS injection, and run using a very messed up scope.
- Using event handler IDL attributes

  Their value is a function reference. You can set them as a JavaScript property:

  ```
  element.onclick = function() {
    show(strings[i]);
  };
  ```

  They are better than event handler content attributes, but they still have the limitation that each element can't have more than one event handler for the same event.
- Using event listeners

  Their value is a function reference. You can set them as in JavaScript using `addEventListener`:

  ```
  element.addEventListener('click', function() {
    show(strings[i]);
  });
  ```

  You can add as many event listeners as you want. You can even use a third argument to say whether you want the event listener to run in the capture phase instead of the bubble one.